# Setting Statusbar padding to NavigationView in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I have an activity which hosts a DrawerLayout and NavigationView from support library. I'm setting a header layout to the navigation view and I want the navigation header height to be "wrap_content". So when I set the height to "wrap_content" the header layout goes behind the status bar.

The result I want is that the navigation drawer should draw behind the status bar but the navigation header should be pushed down by the statusbar height.

Below is the screenshot of what I am getting. Note the "SIGN IN" button going behind the status bar.

[image: screenshot]

Activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Navigation View Header Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:padding="16dp"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:gravity="bottom">

<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_user_name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_email"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign In"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've searched through StackOverflow for a solution but couldn't find it. So someone please shed some light. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

**android:fitsSystemWindows="false"**

and CoordinatorLayout => android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

Comment: Hi it would be nice if you could provide more explanations around your solution. (tip : people are also more likely to accept your solution ;))

Comment: This will cause the drawer to be drawn below the statusbar, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @SpaceBison This *is* the desired behavior. This is also the *standard* behavior. The point is, op wants the *button* not to be displayed below the statusbar. By adding padding on top of it, for example.

Answer (score 7):

First, remember that you cannot draw behind status bar before Lollipop.

#### Solution

For Lollipop+, you should set the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for `DrawerLayout` and leave the default for `NavigationView` .

Then on your activity or fragment after setting the header:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    navigationView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->

        val header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
        header.setPadding(
            header.paddingLeft, 
            header.paddingTop + insets.systemWindowInsetTop,
            header.paddingRight, 
            header.paddingBottom
        )
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

The window is passing a object called `insets` (with dimensions for top, left, bottom, right) to it's childs views. The child views that have the `fitSystemWindows=true` will do nothing with this insets and may send it forward to its children. The views that have it false may use the values to add extra padding or margin to itself.

Set `fitSystemWindows=false` of the `NavigationView` is not working because it is using the insets to apply extra margin to itself. What you want is your header view `LinearLayout` to apply this margin. But there is two intermediate container views inside `NavigationView` that will not pass forward the insets to your `LinearLayout`, so you have to intercept the windows inset before these containers and apply yourself the margin or padding of your header view.

#### What you should never do

Never assume that the window insets will be a fixed value or get them from resources, no matter what the Android version is. Specific devices have specific values for window insets, some have thicker "notches" to fit big cameras, some manufacturers decide to make it thinner than Android recommended specs.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `LinearLayout` as the root element of your header layout. `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc. are basic layouts that ignore the `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute. **I recommend you to use `CoordinatorLayout` as your header layout's root element.** Using `CoordinatorLayout` with its `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute set to `true` will automatically adjust its internal padding to prevent its child elements from being overlapped by system windows such as the status bar.

These info are from [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec), "Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows?" by Ian Lake.

> While the basic layouts (FrameLayout, LinearLayout, etc) use the default behavior, there are a number of layouts that already customize how they react to fitsSystemWindows to fit specific use cases.
>
> ...
>
> CoordinatorLayout also takes advantage of overriding how it handles window insets, allowing the Behavior set on child Views to intercept and change how Views react to window insets, before calling dispatchApplyWindowInsets() on each child themselves. It also uses the fitsSystemWindows flag to know if it needs to paint the status bar background.

To achieve what you want, make sure that you follow this layout structure.

*layout/activity_xxxxx.xml*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- content -->
    ...

    <!-- drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*layout/nav_header.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- content -->
    ...

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```